# Return new array of objects based on several properties of existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I am breaking my head trying to figure how to achieve what I need. My initial array of objects is 70k objects with 15 attributes each. Through filtering and mapping, I have gotten the data set down to what I think are the relevant parts. I need to return a new array of objects based on each of the 4 properties of each object, with their being duplicate `id's` and different `levels` for each `code`. My filtered data looks like so.

```
const arr = [{id: "12345", level: "1", current: "Y", code: "1"}, 
             {id: "12345", level: "0", current: "N", code: "1"},
             {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "2", current: "Y", code: "201"}, 
             {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "Y", code: "401"},
             {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "401"},
             {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "N", code: "301"},
             {id: "121212", level: "0", current: "N", code: "3"},
             {id: "121212", level: "1", current: "N", code: "3"}]
```

What I need to achieve is for each `id` for any `current` of `Y` for each `code`, I need to find the max `level` for that `code`. So for the example above the resulting output would be an array of objects like so:

```
const result = [{id: "12345", max: "1", code: "1"}, 
                {id: "54321", max: "3", code: "201"},
                {id: "54321", max: "1", code: "401"}]
```

I'm not even sure if what I want is possible, or if I'm thinking about it the wrong way. I have been racking my brain all morning trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: if " for any current of Y" then shouldn't ihe max values be 1,0,2 instead of 1,3,1 ?

Comment: @mickl I may have worded it wrong, but for any `code` that has a 'Y' for each `id` I need to find the max of that code for the `id`. I need the max `level` for each code that has a 'Y'

Comment: Thanks, modified my answer, now it returns what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` and `.map()` to get initial values based on `Y` and then `.reduce()` to get max values:

```js
const arr = [{id: "12345", level: "1", current: "Y", code: "1"}, 
             {id: "12345", level: "0", current: "N", code: "1"},
             {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "2", current: "Y", code: "201"}, 
             {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "Y", code: "401"},
             {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "401"},
             {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
             {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "N", code: "301"},
             {id: "121212", level: "0", current: "N", code: "3"},
             {id: "121212", level: "1", current: "N", code: "3"}]

let initialValues = arr.filter(x => x.current === "Y")
         .map(x => ({ id: x.id, max: x.level, code: x.code }));

let result = arr.reduce((result,current) => {
 var value = result.find(x => x.id === current.id && x.code === current.code);
 if(!value) return result;
 if(value.max < current.level) {
  value.max = current.level;
 }
 return result;
}, initialValues);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve a `Array.reduce()` and `Object destructuring`. construct a map with each key a combination of `id` and `code`. Simply use `Object.values()` on the map to get the desired result :

```js
const arr = [{id: "12345", level: "1", current: "Y", code: "1"}, {id: "12345", level: "0", current: "N", code: "1"}, {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "201"}, {id: "54321", level: "2", current: "Y", code: "201"}, {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"}, {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "Y", code: "401"}, {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "401"}, {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"}, {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "N", code: "301"}, {id: "121212", level: "0", current: "N", code: "3"}, {id: "121212", level: "1", current: "N", code: "3"}];
             
const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,{level,current, ...props})=>{
    a[props.id+"_"+props.code] = a[props.id+"_"+props.code] || props;
    a[props.id+"_"+props.code].max = Math.max((a[props.id+"_"+props.code].max || 0), level);
  return a;
},{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce to a Map and take its values

```js
const arr = [{id: "12345", level: "1", current: "Y", code: "1"},
    {id: "12345", level: "0", current: "N", code: "1"},
    {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "201"},
    {id: "54321", level: "2", current: "Y", code: "201"},
    {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
    {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "Y", code: "401"},
    {id: "54321", level: "1", current: "N", code: "401"},
    {id: "54321", level: "3", current: "N", code: "201"},
    {id: "54321", level: "0", current: "N", code: "301"},
    {id: "121212", level: "0", current: "N", code: "3"},
    {id: "121212", level: "1", current: "N", code: "3"}];
    
    
const res = arr.reduce((a, b) =>
  b.current === 'Y' ?
  a.set(b.id + b.code, (a.get(b.id + b.code) || {
    level: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
  }).level < b.level ? b : a.get(b.id + b.code)) :
  a, new Map);
console.log([...res.values()]);
```

Comment: OP is expecting different result

Answer (score 0):

```
const resultObject = (arr, filter) => arr.reduce((sum, element) => {
  const currentInSum = sum[element.id];
  const filterSatisfied = element.current === filter;
  const isHighestLevel = !currentInSum  || currentInSum.level < element.level;
  if(filterSatisfied && isHighestLevel){
     sum[element.id] = element;
  }
  return sum;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(resultObject(arr, "Y"));
```

Basically you want to use an object so that you can check whether the element is already added, and if the current level is higher than the one already added, then replace it, if this is the first occurence then just add it to the object.

Lastly, just get all the values from the object to convert it to an array, you don't care about the keys which is the object's id.

This algorithm takes O(n*2) time to execute, since you have to run through arr once, and then you have to convert all the values in the object into an array